# Okay, so then how am I supposed to sync a soundclip?

Tags: animation, audio

Blender doesn't let me view wave forms or frequencies. I have a small audio clip I want sync perfectly with an animation within a program where I have specific instruments and sound effects coming in at very specific times.

As far as I can tell, blender is playing at 30fps because that is what I set it to in the Render properties menu. What I noticed however is that the visual animation playback in the 3D port was *severely delayed* and out of sync with the audio clip that I 100% bet-my-life-on-it perfectly calculated the equivalent frame rates for when converting from seconds in the audio clip.

Then I noticed I had subdivision surface on, so I turned those off and the animation was then more in sync.

However, when I looked at the frame rate counter in the top-left corner, it kept fluctuating around 30fps, so I won't actually know for sure if it is being properly synced. How do I actually make sure an audio clip is properly synced? Blender is not remotely intuitive in any capacity, I have no idea how video sequences in blender work, I just followed instructions to very basically open the sound clip in the video sequence editor (how is that not synonymous with movie clip editor?), then I hit the play button and hoped that the animation would play at the same time as the clip and luckily it did.

Then, as I mentioned there are other instruments in the audio clip. Blender doesn't seem to have a way to view the waveform so I don't know how to see sound and frequency spikes in it, and instead of manually calculating the nearest frame of thousands of drum beats, is there some other way I can, as precisely as possible, know "when" a certain drum beat is playing so that I can modify the animation accordingly to sync with that beat?

You might think that at regular intervals that one could efficiently calculate exactly when each beat is, but "bars" in music does not convert easily to seconds and then to frames, they are always off by some decimal number which means I have to arbitrarily decide how to round off each time, and since I'm not going to get that perfectly without manually listening to it, it would be better to simply listen to the audio clip in real time and try and sync it in the first place.

The problem with listening to it in real time? Well, that is the first problem I mentioned where blender keeps fluctuating around 30 fps instead of just being at 30 fps, so even if I hear when a particular drum beat is playing, I won't actually know if that is the right frame.

Comment: You can start with [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/vse/sequencer/strips/sound.html). And there are lots of good Blender audio tutorials on YouTube and throughout the web. How much searching have you done?

Comment: Change the Sync Mode drop down to "AV Sync" and then fro the View menu select Waveforms and select Waveforms On. Can take a short while to generate the Wave forms.